# Run script depending on active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to execute a script based on an active sheet the user is. So, the menu code is the following:

```
function onOpenInstalledTrigger(){
  app.createMenu('Benefits')
    .addItem('Generate benefits', 'setBenefits')
    .addToUi();
}
```

And then, to execute the script only when the sheet `VT` is active I wrote:

```
function setBenefits(){
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName() == 'VT'){
    benefitsValue()
    discountValue()
    netValue()
  } else {
    app.alert('It must be active on sheet VT')
  }
}
```

But when I add this condition, I get an error:

> Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for
> SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName.

How can I only execute the code when the user is at the right sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getActiveSheet().getName()` to get the name of the current active sheet.

```
function setBenefits(){
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'VT'){
    benefitsValue()
    discountValue()
    netValue()
  } else {
    app.alert('It must be active on sheet VT')
  }
}
```

You have it confused with `getSheetByName`.

`getSheetByName` needs a parameter (sheet name) and it returns the sheet.

`getName` returns the name of the spreadsheet/sheet depending on where you use it.

#### Output:

[image: output]
[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [getName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getname)
- [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getsheetbynamename)

#### EDIT:

- The issue "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1." is caused by the commands outside the functions trying to access the active sheet's range that isn't available.

#### FIX:

- There are many ways to do this, but the easiest modification you can do is access VT directly. Since you only need to do this in VT sheet, access the VT sheet instead.

#### Modification:

```
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('VT');
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: It worked when the active sheet is 'VT'. But otherwise it runs with an error: "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1."

Comment: There is an issue with the commands you execute in the else part. can you also show it? @Seyfertt

Comment: It is literally equals to your answer. [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/1qh1aeg)

Comment: can you share a sample sheet and make it publicly editable? I'd like to see the test why it causes that error on yours. That shouldn't be the case. As I have shown above, the output is expected and doesn't have any error. @Seyfertt

Comment: `app.alert('It must be active on sheet VT')` won't cause any type of that exception as that doesn't access the sheet. Unless shown in a sample sheet, I can't seem to understand how that error pops up in the else part. @Seyfertt

Comment: @Seyfertt, kindly make sure to include your script on that public sample sheet and have the error reproduced so I can take a look at it. I'll be waiting for the sheet. edit your answer and include the link. Thanks

Comment: It is here: [Sheet + script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fi87BLz6f0HHv4CHsrGbpYnQdYWzZGSc43MfmIyOBkQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236363/discussion-between-nazia-and-seyfertt).

Answer (score 1):

try this instead :

```
function setBenefits(){
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() == 'VT'){
    benefitsValue()
    discountValue()
    netValue()
  } else {
    app.alert('It must be active on sheet VT')
  }
}
```

Your function has two problems :

- getSheetByName takes a string as an argument ( cf https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String) )
- even if getSheetByName had sent you a sheet, you can't compare a sheet with a string

Comment: It worked when the active sheet is 'VT' but it throws an error otherwise 'Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.'

Answer (score 1):

### You should use the `onSelectionChange(e)` trigger:

To execute a code when switching between different sheets you can instead use [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee).

The following example will execute some code when you switch from a **different** sheet to **VT**:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {       
   const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   if (as.getName() == 'VT'){ 
          benefitsValue();
          discountValue();
          netValue();
   }
}
```

Comment: Currently the user goes to menu 'Generate benefits' to execute the code. He chooses when to execute by clicking it. This trigger automatically executes it.

Comment: @Seyfertt consider upvoting good answers :)